# Trying to translate English text to different languages using py-translate

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror

I have list of words in a csv file. I am converting those words in  different  languages.
I am trying to use py-translate but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/translate/__init__.py", line 
10, in <module>
    from .coroutines import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/translate/coroutines.py", 
line 19, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures
```

Comment: Did you try `pip install futures`?

Comment: @errata i use `pip install translate` and no ,i haven't use `pip install feature`.

Comment: and with that you need to install future, so use pip install futures

Comment: @wizard You should definitely try to run `pip install futures`...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using python version less than 3. Install
`pip install futures`
to solve it for python versions less than 3. it is built in with python 3 and above